# How do I install and use Aref Ruqaa font on macTex?

Tags: fonts, mactex, installing-fonts

I already have my preamble set up and ready to implement a font style, but I do not know how to 'install' or add it to the list of available fonts in MacTex.

My preamble is as follows.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, mathabx, thmtools, fontspec, fancyhdr, geometry}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{subdefinition}{}[definition]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Amiri}
```

Comment: Sorry, do you want to install Aref Ruqaa or Amiri?

Comment: First look for [a CTAN package to install.](https://ctan.org/pkg/amiri) If there isn’t one, download the font from its webpage and install it in your System Font Book.

Comment: I would like to install both actually.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks.

Comment: @Mecca, I think that you may told us what you did to solve your own question.